# How can I set the time in postgres in order to test timezone behaviour using RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec

I want to be able to test the behaviour of a scheduler component across different timezones. However, the functionality to trigger scheduled behaviour uses time based queries within postgres:

e.g.

```
# find reminders which have not been sent for "today" in the local date
Schedule.where('evening_reminder_last_sent_on_local_date != 
                                     DATE( NOW() AT TIME ZONE time_zone )')
```

I would like to be able to test this behaviour in RSpec and ensure that it plays correctly through the day and that if I send a Japanese user a reminder at 1am UTC on the 25th Dec,  then at 10pm UTC, their reminder for "today" will show up as *not* have been sent (since it's about 7am the next day in Japan).

However, in order to do this I need to be able to set the datetime in postgres. Is this possible?

### Please note... this is not about stubbing Rails' time

The challenge is not to stub the time in Rails - I know how to do that. The problem is how to set the time in Postgres.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postgres uses the date / time setting of the underlying OS (at least on UNIX-like systems). To stage various timestamps, you would have to set the time of the OS, with the `date` command.

I would certainly not recommend that on a system that does anything else of importance. cronjobs can run haywire and other unpleasant side effects.

Instead, replace the function `now()` with a user-defined server-side function like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION now_test()
  RETURNS timestamptz AS $func$SELECT '2013-12-01 12:34'::timestamptz$func$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

(The above cast assumes the current time zone setting of the session. Alternatively, you can provide a time zone or time offset with the literal.)
Then you can test your code with:

```
Schedule.where('evening_reminder_last_sent_on_local_date != 
                             DATE(now_test() AT TIME ZONE time_zone)')
```

Modify the above SQL function above with various timestamps and you are good to go.

Comment: This is excellent, very good suggestion. However it opens up another question for me which is how to manage postgres functions in Rails. I've asked this as a separate question and would love to know your thoughts - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314724/how-do-you-define-postgres-functions-in-rails-and-what-is-their-scope-and-lifeti

Answer (score 2):

The previous suggestion is indeed very good but as I wanted to easily test my query with [Delorean](https://github.com/bebanjo/delorean) gem, I came up with this workaround:

```
Schedule.where('evening_reminder_last_sent_on_local_date != 
               DATE( ?::timestamp AT TIME ZONE time_zone )', Time.now)
```

I took the previous example just for the sake, but I had to manipulate times in Postgres with the `now()` function. I couldn't just inject my ruby time instead without casting it with `::timestamp`.

Moreover, in your case, maybe you could use [timestamptz](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar case except instead of modifying the timezones, I wanted to apply an offset.  This let me synchronize postgres's responses to `NOW()` with my appliction's responses to `datetime.now()` (tampered via [libfaketime](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime)).

I ended up with one statement that renamed `now()` to `system_now()`, but only if `system_now()` didn't already exist:

```
DO $$
    DECLARE
    found_func pg_proc%rowtype;
    BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM pg_proc WHERE proname = 'system_now' INTO found_func;
    IF FOUND THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'DB Already Faked';
    ELSE
        RAISE NOTICE'Faking DB Time';
        ALTER FUNCTION now RENAME TO system_now;
    END IF;
END $$;
```

...and another one that redefined `NOW()` to include the offset:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION now() RETURNS timestamptz
AS $func$
    SELECT system_now() + INTERVAL '1225288 seconds';
$func$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```